# Estoy intentando reinstalar FusionDirectory para ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ldap

Estoy siguiendo este manual, pero me peta en el momento en el que busco localhost/fusiondirectory
https://fusiondirectory-user-manual.readthedocs.io/en/1.3/install/debian/debian-fd-install.html

Hay un post similar en el que dice que instale el php7.0-ldap, lo he hecho y el error persiste.
El problema esta en que tenia el FusionDirectory ya instalado y lo he intentado borrar pero parece que se ha quedado algún archivo molestando.

[image: Error del php]

Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ldap_connect()
> in /usr/share/fusiondirectory/include/class_ldap.inc:1440 Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 /usr/share/fusiondirectory/setup/class_setupStep_Ldap.inc(114): LDAP::get_naming_contexts('ldap://localhos...') #1
>
> /usr/share/fusiondirectory/setup/class_setupStep_Ldap.inc(101):
> Step_Ldap->update_base_choices() #2
> /usr/share/fusiondirectory/setup/class_setup.inc(59):
> Step_Ldap->__construct(Object(setup)) #3
> /usr/share/fusiondirectory/setup/main.inc(24): setup->__construct() #4
> /usr/share/fusiondirectory/html/setup.php(99):
> require_once('/usr/share/fusi...') #5 {main} thrown in
> /usr/share/fusiondirectory/include/class_ldap.inc on line 1440

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Por favor copia y pega como texto el mensaje de error pues al momento como esta es poco legible

Comment: Ya lo tienes, he editado el post.